# Oracle JVM on OS X

Tags: java, macos, environment

I'm trying to update my JVM and downloaded the dmg from java.com and installed it and now I see java has been updated to 1.7.0_55, but for some reasons /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7 doesn't return the new jdk but the old one (native to OS X).

```
chienandalusialocal:TempEc ngw$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.7".
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

How should I fix this? Shouldn't the installer configure a working environment?

TIA,
  ngw

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You need to update your `JAVA_HOME` enviroment variable to point at the JVM you want to use; In factory distributions of OSX, the `JAVA_HOME` (specified in your ~/.bash_profile) will point to the JDK 1.6.0 installed in `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`</strike>

A simple fix; You need to change the `JAVA_HOME` variable at login, so you need to change a line in the text file `~/.bash_profile`, which is run whenever you login.

In terminal:

type: `open /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` to open Finder in the location of your JVMs. Get the folder **name** of the JVM you want to use, and save that for later.

type: `open -a TextEdit ~/.bash_profile`, and the file will open in TextEdit.

look for a line that says:

`export JAVA_HOME="/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home"` or

```
JAVA_HOME="/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home"
export JAVA_HOME
```

and change to

`export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/YOUR_JDK/Contents/Home"`

where YOUR_JDK is the folder name of the JVM you want to use that you found earlier.

Restart terminal to test the effects, and type `java -V` to see if it is working.

See https://superuser.com/questions/490425/how-do-i-switch-between-java-7-and-java-6-on-os-x-10-8-2

Comment: Actually, I use `/usr/libexec/java_home` to set my `JAVA_HOME` in `~/.bash_profile`. `/usr/libexec/java_home` is a utility that should, as far as I understand, look for JVM's in specific places (where Apple's JVM's were installed, and where Oracle's JVM's are installed)

Comment: @Darsstar Derp, see http://superuser.com/questions/490425/how-do-i-switch-between-java-7-and-java-6-on-os-x-10-8-2